# Reduce para object?

Tags: javascript, objetos

eu estou fazendo um código aqui, com o seguinte objeto:

```
{
    path: 'mtw',
    return: 'hi',
    obj: {
        path: 'he-mele-no-lilo',
        return: 'hi',
        obj: {
            path: 'hawaiian',
            return: 'hi',
            obj: {
                path: 'swiss',
                return: 'hi',
                obj: {
                    path: 'altendorf',
                    return: 'hi',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e eu preciso entrar em cada obj e assim pegar todos os "obj", eu tentei fazer isso com reduce:

```
const res = arr.reduce(function(s: any, a: any){
    console.log(s);
    console.log(a);
    return s;
  }, {});
```

mas ele não entra em todos os objetos, portanto, como eu posso fazer, estou fazendo algo errado?

Edit: Eu procuro um resultado como [{path: 'mtw', return: 'hi'}, {path: 'he-mele-no-lilo', return: 'hi'}, path: 'hawaiian', return: 'hi']

Comment: Qual é o resultado que procuras? podes dar um exemplo do que `res` deveria ser?

Comment: res deveria ser: 
`[{path: 'mtw', return: 'hi'}, {path: 'he-mele-no-lilo', return: 'hi'}, path: 'hawaiian', return: 'hi']`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O reduce não é o método próprio para isso. Não é porque vai iterar somente o numero de vezes que o `length` do array que lhe é dado.

O que precisas é de uma função recursiva, que se chame a si própria e vá extraindo nos níveis internos.

Algo assim:

```js
const input = {
  path: 'mtw',
  return: 'hi',
  obj: {
    path: 'he-mele-no-lilo',
    return: 'hi',
    obj: {
      path: 'hawaiian',
      return: 'hi',
      obj: {
        path: 'swiss',
        return: 'hi',
        obj: {
          path: 'altendorf',
          return: 'hi',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const extractObj = (root) => {
  const res = [{
    path: root.path,
    return: root.return
  }];
  if (root.obj) {
    res.push(...extractObj(root.obj));
  }
  return res;
}

const res = extractObj(input);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Sua resposta está correta, obrigado!